# Error in FirebaseUser for authentication using flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm beginner to this flutter. Currently i am trying to do email authentication for sign-up. I already tried few solution from website/github/youtube, but it turns to the same error which is on `FirebaseUser`. Here i attach my code segment.

```
class _RegisterEmailSectionState extends State<_RegisterEmailSection> {

  void _register() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = (await
    _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _emailController.text,
      password: _passwordController.text,
    )
    ).user;
    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        _success = true;
        _userEmail = user.email;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _success = true;
      });
    }
  }
  void dispose() {
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  bool _success;
  String _userEmail;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            controller: _emailController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
            validator: (String value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _passwordController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText:
            'Password'),
            validator: (String value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  _register();
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(_success == null
                ? ''
                : (_success
                ? 'Successfully registered ' + _userEmail
                : 'Registration failed')),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
 }
```

Is there something that I miss out? I don't know why `FirebaseUser` error in my code. I assume that it is error due to different version of firebase. I found someone from the flutter community and they said try to changed it to be `Authresult` but the same error come out.

Can anyone help me on this issue? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Change

```dart
    final FirebaseUser user = ...
```

to

```dart
    final User user = ...
```

[Here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html) is the class you trying to get here. It has the type of `User`.