# Undefined class 'FirebaseUser' and even after changing it, iget errors in FirebaseAuth.instance

Tags: firebase, flutter, email, authentication, passwords

Hello everyone can anyone please help me,

at first i wrote

```
 Future<void> signIn() async {
    //we validate fields here
    final formState = _formKey.currentState;
    if (formState!.validate()) {
      // login to firebase
      formState.save();
      FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
    }
  }
```

then i read that "Firebaseuser" became "User", so after changing it i got errors in FirebaseAuth.instance

```
A value of type 'UserCredential' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'User'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'User'
```

so then, i changed FireBaseAuth to UserCredential, so i got another error

```
The getter 'instance' isn't defined for the type 'UserCredential'.
Try importing the library that defines 'instance', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'instance'
```

What should i do? and how do i re-write my code so it works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in FirebaseUser for authentication using flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66760058/error-in-firebaseuser-for-authentication-using-flutter)

Comment: @SimonSot thank you, but no i tried it and i get erroros in firebaseAuth.instance

Comment: The thing is that you are most likely get that code from outdated source. Some time ago firebaseAuth used class `FirebaseUser`, that is now deprecated. And now getter for user is `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser`, that will get you a class `User`. Please check this link it has all data to learn about work with this api https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage

Comment: oh okay thank you so much, and yes you are right i'm learning from a video of 2018

Comment: most likely you will be interested in usage part - email/password register and signin, there is a code snippet that you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
  UserCredential userCredential = await 
  FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: _email,
    password: _password
  );
 User user = userCredential.user; 
 print(user);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    print('No user found for that email.');
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
  }
}
```

FirebaseUser has been replaced with User.

Comment: thank you i tried it but then i got an error telling me to change 'User user = userCredential.user ' to 'User? user = userCredential.user ', and i guess now it works